# Problem duplicating and separately selecting between objects

Tags: selection-tools

I'm wondering if there is a setting I am missing or even if I need to re-install.  I can't see what I am actually doing incorrectly.  I cannot duplicate an object and individually select between them.

Specifically in seconds 20 - 28 of this video I can't accomplish.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc-zPyV1kew

My steps are:

1) Make new file which opens default blender cube.
2) Click cube, <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, drag new cube left.
3) Attempt to select original cube - I can't.

My aim is to duplicate an object I've created in another file I have, resize and edit that, and be able to separately edit both objects in that session - but I can't even dupe the default shape properly. Any direction appreciated.

Comment: If you press *A* twice, then press *G* does everything move?

Comment: UPDATE:  I CAN seem to select between the, but not by pointing and clicking...I have to go to the tree under All Scenes and select an object...how to I make it so I can just point and click?

Comment: ANNNDDD.... of course, we select with the RIGHT mouse button.  Doh.  sorry for the waste of bandwidth